# Saving a Gmail attachment to Google Docs

Tags: gmail, google-drive, attachment

Is there a way to save an email attachment in Gmail to Google Docs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you get an email with a Word (.doc), Powerpoint or PDF attachment then there are two links next to it, 'View' and 'Download'. When you click on 'View' the document is opened by Google Docs and there is a link at the top to allow you to 'Save in Google Docs'

Excel attachments give you three options, 'View at HTML' ,'Open as a Google spreadsheet' and 'Download'.

Answer (score 1):

For files that you can't open directly in Docs, but want to save there, you can save it to your local machine, and then use the "Upload ..." button on the front page of Docs.  [There is a 1 GB limit for documents saved, but not converted to GD format.](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=50092)

Answer (score 1):

New features are introduced. From [Attachment in GMail with Google Drive](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2013/11/attachments-in-gmail-now-with-power-of.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.

But some file formats (most notably PDFs), you can view online by clicking the "View" link next to the attachment.

When you are then viewing the file, there is a link to save it to Google Docs.